# Store the UUID and IP of a machine in a file through batch file

Tags: batch-file, uuid

I need to generate a text file with data of the UUID and IP of a machine through batch file, something like this:

> CAA8A570-86FF-81E4-3398-0071C21A28CE  192.168.0.0

I used these commands but I can't figure out how to put the info in the same file.

```
wmic csproduct get "UUID" > C:\UUID.txt
ipconfig /all | find /i "phy" > C:\MAC.txt
```

Comment: must the format be in the same line in the same file as per your example?

Comment: also, `ipconfig /all | find /i "phy"` gets mac address not IP, you mention you want IP, also if it is mac you want, it has more than one mac, which one to use?

Comment: Read about [redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

Comment: Yes, what i need is to identify with a unique id the connected machines and get also the IP. These PC are not in my domain. The users will execute the batch and write the info in a shared directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get the IP address and the UUID of a computer through batch file. However, it is unclear what you want to do with them. So, I will show you the way to get them and I will store their value in a variable. Do whatever you want then:

```bat
@echo off
rem Script to get the UUID and IP address of this computer.

rem Get IP address:
for /F "tokens=2 delims=(:" %%A IN ('ipconfig /all ^| findstr /c:"IPv4"') do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        rem Set the IP address into the IP_address variable:
        set "IP_address=%%B"
    )
)

rem Get UUID:
for /F %%A IN ('(wmic csproduct get "UUID"^) ^| findstr /c:"-"') do (
    rem Set the UUID in the UUID variable:
    set "UUID=%%A"
)

rem Echo the results
echo We have found that this computer has a UUID of %UUID%.
echo We have also found the IP address of this computer. It is: %IP_address%
```

If you want to redirect them to a file in the format mentioned in your question, use:

```bat
(echo %UUID%  %IP_address%)>filename.txt
```

And if you want to append them, use:

```bat
(echo %UUID%  %IP_address%)>>filename.txt
```

You may understand better how my code works, if I show you the output of each command processed.

---

#### `ipconfig /all | findstr /c:"Ipv4"`:

The output of it, is (for me):

```bat
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxx.xxx.x.x(Preferred)
```

I am not sure if you are getting these parenthesis.

The `for /F` loop which processes the command has `tokens=2` and `delims=(:` options.

- `delims=(:` option means not to parse into tokens the characters `(` and `:`. The tokens then, will be (separated by `|`): `IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . | xxx.xxx.x.x|Preferred)`. I have removed the characters `(:` as you can see. The token which contains the IP address is the second one, so I select it using:
- `tokens=2` option.

Because there is one space in its start, I make another loop in this to remove the spaces in the start, using `tokens=*` option.

Finally, the IP address is set into the `IP_address` variable and it is ready for use!

---

#### `(wmic csproduct get "UUID") | findstr /c:"-"`:

The output of this command is just the UUID (no additional loops here):

```bat
F5A91381-529E-11CB-A155-BF406BD05412
```

So, I just set it to a variable (`UUID`) and it is ready for use!

---

For seeing what 'redirect' and what 'append' means, I suggest the following links for reading:

- https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php
- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Also, I suggest opening a cmd, typing the following commands and reading carefully their output:

- `for /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `echo /?`

which will surely help you understand my code.

Comment: The problem with this code is that you are gathering the last `IPv4` that results from `ipconfig`. This means if you have multiple network adapters, it will not display the active or current adapter/IP adress.